# Как обнулить отступ маркера в списке?

Tags: html, css

Как обнулить или изменить отступ маркера в списке. По умолчанию отступ маркера уже задан, возможно ли его отменить с помощью padding или margin другим способом. Я решил через margin-left: -N px. Код ниже

```css
html,
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.main-menu {
 width: 250px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 0;
 background: #3296ad;
 list-style-position: inside;
}

.main-menu li {
 padding: 10px 15px;
 margin-bottom: -3px;
 list-style-type: circle;
 color: #ffffff;
 border: 3px solid #b4e6e5;
}

.main-menu li a {
 /* margin-left: -15px;*/
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #f5ffe7
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Menu</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <nav>
  <ul class="main-menu">
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Beatae, enim.</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Perferendis, unde!</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Inventore, assumenda.</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Recusandae, quae?</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Iusto, quia.</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/faq/kak-izmenit-otstup-sleva-ot-markerov-spiska

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть еще такой вариант `before`:

```css
html,
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.main-menu {
 width: 250px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 0;
 background: #3296ad;
}

.main-menu li { 
    margin-bottom: -3px;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 3px solid #b4e6e5;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.main-menu li:before {
  content: '';
  list-style-type: circle;
  display: list-item;
  float: left;
  width: 1px;
  margin: 0 -10px 0 10px;
}

.main-menu li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #f5ffe7;   
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Beatae, enim.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Perferendis, unde!</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Inventore, assumenda.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Recusandae, quae?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Iusto, quia.</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Но тоже с отрицательным отступом, решение которое вполне приемлемое (как и Ваш `margin-left: -15px;`) !

Также из той серии, что и отрицательный отступ - это `a {translateX(-15px); }`

Comment: А он не имел введу от маркера до текста?

Comment: @Yuri, так вот не понятно что он имел ввиду